# Change context in $.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the context for jQuery's `$.each` method. What did I miss?

```
$.each.call(this, [1,2,3], function(){
    console.log(this); // expecting to see the window object
});

var foo = { bar: 1 };
$.each.call(foo, [1,2,3], function(){
    console.log(this); // expecting to see the foo object
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/53jhrbh5/

Comment: `this` will always be one the numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.each` uses `call` and `apply` internally to set the right `this` value in the callback, something like `callback.apply(obj[i])`, so it uses the array for the `this` value, and calling the method with `call` won't change that.

It works something like this

```
function each(obj, callback, args) {
    var value, i = 0,
        length   = obj.length,
        isArray  = isArraylike(obj);

    if (args) {
        if (isArray) {
            for (; i < length; i++) {
                value = callback.apply(obj[i], args);
            }
        } else {
            for (i in obj) {
                value = callback.apply(obj[i], args);
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

See how it calls the callback, passing in each value from the passed array or object as the `this` value, and that means you can't change it by calling the `$.each` method differently, as it's `this` value has nothing to do with the `this` value of the callback function, that's being set by jQuery.

You could `$.proxy` it, or `bind()` it, but the easy way is just to use a variable

```
var self = this;

$.each(arr, function() {
     console.log( self );
});
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I wanted to know

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to do this

1) Reference window from outside

```
var self = this;
$.each.call(this, [1,2,3], function(){
    console.log(self); // expecting to see the window object
});
```

2) Bind the function to a particular scope

```
$.each.call(this, [1,2,3], function(){
    console.log(this); // expecting to see the window object
}.bind(this));
```

3) Use ES6 arrow function which binds to current context (Can't use in most browsers without some 6->5 conversion)

```
$.each.call(this, [1,2,3], () => {
   console.log(this); // expecting to see the window object
});
```

4) Just reference window directly

```
$.each.call(this, [1,2,3], () => {
   console.log(window); // expecting to see the window object
});
```

Comment: Complete answer! Just missing the jQuery way for older browsers support: `$.each([1,2,3], $.proxy(function(){
    console.log(this); // expecting to see the window object
}, this));`

Answer (score 3):

Just use `Function.bind` on the callback to specify what context you want the function to run in.

```
$.each([1,2,3], (function(){
    console.log(this); // expecting to see the window object
}).bind(this));
```

Internally jQuery uses `ThisBinding` modifiers like `apply`, `call`. So, `this` will always be a `Number`, unless you specify the context of the callback to be run.